# How to change the admin port using the Google App engine launcher?

Tags: google-app-engine, launcher

It's easy to change the port of the application using the launcher. Go to `Edit>>Application Settings` (or alternatively <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) and change the port. Since I was getting an error similar to the one given below, I changed the application port from `8080` to `48080`. Unfortunately, I am not able to change the admin port from `8000` to `48000`, because of which I am getting the following error.

> google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8000

I also tried the method illustrated in the following image (my reference being this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver)):
[image]

Regardless of what I try, my web-browsers (`Chrome` and `Firefox`) return a message similar to `This webpage is not available`. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you want the equals sign.  Try `--admin_port 48000`

Comment: I tried it; however, I get the error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '--admin_port 48000'`.

Comment: I have seen this before, when I had a crashed instance running on the port.  You may have a frozen Python script running on that port.  On a Mac, I can go to Activity Monitor and kill the process.  Not sure if you can do that via task manager in Windows.  You may need to restart machine.

Comment: Yeah.. that did it. If you write this as the answer I will accept it. I am not sure if this worthy of a Q&A. But I guess subsequent noobs like me will come across such a problem and may find this useful. Hence I don't plan to delete this question myself — let the mods decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before, when I had a crashed instance running on the port. You may have a frozen Python script running on that port. On a Mac, I can go to Activity Monitor and kill the process. Not sure if you can do that via task manager in Windows. You may need to restart machine.